# Fortran issue with multiple cpus

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran

I'm running some code written in fortan. It is made of several subroutines and I share variables among them using global variables specified in a module.

The problem occurs when using multiple cpus. In one subroutine the code should update a value of a local variable by the value of a global variable. It so happens that in some random passes though the subroutine the code does not update the variables when I run it using multiple cpus. However if I pause it and make it go up to force the code to pass in the piece of code that updates the variable it works! Magic! I've then implemented a loop that checks if the variable was updated and tries to go back using (GOTO's) in the code to make it update the variables.... but for 2 tries it still sometimes do not update the variables. If I run the code with only one core then it works fine.... Any ideas??

Thanks

Piece of code:

```
Subroutine1() !Where the variable A0 should be updated
                nTries = 0
 777               IF (nItems.NE.0) THEN
                    DO J = 1,nItems
                        IF (nint(mDATA(J,3)).EQ.nint(XCOORD+U1NE0)
 & .AND. nint(mDATA(J,4)).EQ.nint(YCOORD+U2NE0) .AND. 
 2              nint(mDATA(J,5)).EQ.nint(ZCOORD+U3NE0)) THEN
                            A0 = mDATA(J,1)
                            JNODE = mDATA(J,2)
                            EXIT
                        ELSE
                            A0 = A02
                        ENDIF
                    ENDDO

                IF (A0.EQ.ZERO) THEN !If the variable was not updated
                    IF (nTries.LE.2) THEN
                        nTries = nTries + 1
                        GOTO 777
                    ENDIF
                    write(6,*) "ZERO A0", IELEM, JTYPE
                    A0 = MAXT
                ENDIF
```

Comment: What do you use for running "on multiple cpus"?

Comment: Hi! I'm running a finite element analysis and I'm using a comercial program called abaqus which has a functionality that allows the user to run models using multiple cpu cores. I just need to specify in the DOS command "cpus=number". I don't know how the program then handles the computation but the problem is that one core is going ahead of the other in the computations and the information to update the variable (namely U1NE0,U2NE0,U3NE0) is not yet available at the time it is called by that core.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know how Abaqus interacts with your FORTRAN subroutines, nor is it clear from the above code what is going wrong, but what you're running into seems to be a classical example of a "race condition," which what you're calling "one core going ahead of the other."

A general comment is that `GOTO`s and global variables are extremely dangerous in that they make programs very hard to reason about. These problems compound once you start parallelizing. If Abaqus is doing some kind of "black box" computation that it is responsible for parallelizing, you (as a user who is only preprocessing and postprocessing the data) should be insulated from this. However, from the above, it sounds like you're doing some stuff that is interleaved with the Abaqus parallel computation. In that case, you need to make sure everything you're doing is thread-safe. Among many other things, you absolutely need to make sure you're not writing to any global variables.

Another comment is that your checking of `A0` is basically a lock called a "spinlock." This is one way of making things thread-safe, but locks have pitfalls of their own. If Abaqus doesn't give you a way to synchronize all of the threads and guarantee that it's done with its job, some sort of lock like this may be the way to go.